# Angular $http authorization not used?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer

I'm trying to send a GET request that requires some authorization, however it seems Angular is not keen on sending the required header as well. At least it's not showing up on the network tab in IE.

My code is like this:

```
var authString = 'NTLM ' + this.base64Encode('username' + ':' + 'passowrd');
$http.get('link/to/api', { headers: { Authorization: authString } })
```

Am I missing something, or just doing it wrong?

Comment: try like this-> {headers: { 'Authorization': authString }}

Comment: @manivannan thanks, that was so dumb of me!